# Quiero que el título de la imagen esté desaparecido y cuando pase el mouse por encima, aparezca: lo logro con CSS, pero no con SASS

Tags: css, html5, css3, sass

Tengo este problema que cuando lo hago con CSS me deja pero con SASS no. Quiero que el título de la imagen esté desaparecido y cuando pase el mouse por encima, aparezca. En CSS tengo un contenedor de una imagen y un span, al igual que en SASS, pero no me lo muestra.

Paso el HTML CON CSS y SASS por último.

HTML

```html
<div class="content-img">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="./ASSETS/IMG/2-0-batmoon.png" alt="vampires" />
        <span class="name">
          <span class="txt">Luna con Murcielagos </span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="./ASSETS/IMG/2-1-dragon.png" alt="dragon" />
        <span class="name">
          <span class="txt">Dragon Chino</span>
        </span>
      </div>
```

CSS

```css
.content-img .image .name {
  background-color: #202020;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}

.content-img .image:hover .name {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-img">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="./ASSETS/IMG/2-0-batmoon.png" alt="vampires" />
        <span class="name">
          <span class="txt">Luna con Murcielagos </span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="./ASSETS/IMG/2-1-dragon.png" alt="dragon" />
        <span class="name">
          <span class="txt">Dragon Chino</span>
        </span>
      </div>
```

SASS

```css
.name {
      background-color: #202020;
      border-radius: 15px;
      color: #fff;
      display: none;
      min-width: 100px;
      width: 150px;

      &:hover .name {
        display: inline;
      }
```

Probe haciendolo y me sigue fallando, no se si sera un problema de especificidad o que

Answer (score 3):

En SASS, para obtener como resultado lo mismo que tenes en CSS, podrías hacerlo así:

```
.content-img .image { 

    .name {
      background-color: #202020;
      border-radius: 15px;
      color: #fff;
      display: none;
      min-width: 100px;
      width: 150px;
    }
    &:hover .name {
      display: inline;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sabes que no lo habia leido bien? Recien acabo de sacarlo yo, y me doy cuenta que ya me lo habias dicho, disculpa marcos la proxima leo mejor :)

Comment: @Jose si la respuesta te fue de ayuda, [marcala como aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba anidando los selectores de la siguiente forma:

```
.content-img {
  .image {
    .name {
      background-color: #202020;
      border-radius: 15px;
      color: #fff;
      display: none;
      min-width: 100px;
      width: 150px;

      &:hover {
        display: inline;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: probé hacerlo y no me muestra ni el texto.